# Putting an old psu in a slightly newer pc

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

I have a PC and I think the PSU is finished; as the computer shows zero signs of life when plugged into the power and the power button is pressed. I have a slightly older PC with a PSU that I think is working. The newer PSU says max 240w in a table-like structure. It also says peak: 300w and then rated: 250w. The older PSU that I think is working says max 220w, then some more information , below that, max 380w and some more information and below that, max 400w and some more information. Would this older PSU work in the slightly newer PC or would the older PSU have a negative impact on the slightly newer PC.

Comment: If the plugs all fit, go for it! Without knowing the exact spec of each & every component in the build, it's the surest test. If it crashes the first time you run a game, you need a bigger one.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks I'm just planning to run Ubuntu. I'll try it out anyway. Thanks very much!